# How do I use only css to keep a drop down menu open when an item in the menu is selected?

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm using this css code for my SharePoint site and it currently shows the sub-menu when the main menu item is hovered over. However, when I select an item from the main menu, the sub-menu is hidden again. I want the submenu to remain open if I click on an item and go to the corresponding page so I know which page I am currently on. How do I keep the sub-menu open to show which page I am currently on?

```
#sideNavBox .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox ul ul {
 display: none;
}

#sideNavBox .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Plz provide the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:focus` pseudo-class, Like:

```
#sideNavBox .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox ul li:focus ul {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the menu still collapses after I click on the sub-menu item.

Comment: I dont have the main css file. I just followed Option 2 from this link: http://www.moresharepoint.net/2015/09/collapsible-current-navigation-in.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSTL you can check your current path and if it matches with any menu item add class with 'c:if'. It's doable with JS too.

```js
$('.c-navbar__menu-item').each(function(i){
  if(window.location.pathname === '/'){
      $('.mainMenu li > a:first-child').addClass("isSelected");
  }else if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)>=0){
      $('.mainMenu li > a:eq('+i+')').addClass("isSelected");
  }
});
```

```css
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.mainMenu {list-style-type: none; display: flex; background: #363636}
.mainMenu li {position: relative;}
.mainMenu li a {display: block; padding: 5px 10px; color: #FFF; transition: .3s; cursor: pointer}
.mainMenu li a:hover {background: #ffaa00ad; color: #000}
.mainMenu li .subMenu {position: absolute; display: none; flex-direction: column; list-style-type: none; width: 100%; background: #000}
.mainMenu li .subMenu li a {display: block; padding: 2px 5px; color: #FFF;}
.mainMenu li:hover .subMenu {display: flex}

.mainMenu li .subMenu.isSelected {display: flex;}
a.isSelected {background: #ffaa00ad; color: #000 !important}
```

```html
<ul class="mainMenu">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/contact" class="isSelected">Contact</a>
    <ul class="subMenu isSelected">
      <li><a class="isSelected">item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>item 2</a></li>
      <li><a>item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Blog</a></li>
  <li><a>Product</a></li>
  <li><a>Support</a></li>
</ul>
```